# Remote application through Powershell - Sudden OutOfMemoryException

Tags: windows, powershell, ssis, network-protocols

I have an SSIS package that runs an executable by using Powershell. This worked fine for more than a year, but all of the sudden I get this strange error. I've isolated the command:

```
& '\\iguana01\VMMa\Process e-Invoice\ProcesseInvoice.exe' @('/countfiles','46')
```

If I run this command on my own PC there is no problem
[image]

But if I run this same command on the server (2012) then I get this strange error
[image]

This error dissapears when I run it on the 2012 server from a local folder
[image]

The event viewer doesn't give me that much more information, .NET Runtime 1026 error

```
Application: ProcesseInvoice.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.OutOfMemoryException
Stack:
   at ProcesseInvoice.Program.Main(System.String[])
```

And an application error (1000)

```
Faulting application name: ProcesseInvoice.exe, version: 2.2.4.0, time stamp: 0x5857fbf7
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 6.1.7601.17651, time stamp: 0x4e211319
Exception code: 0xe0434352
Fault offset: 0x0000b9bc
Faulting process id: 0x4488
Faulting application start time: 0x01d34be3a1f4ea5d
Faulting application path: \\iguana01\VMMa\Process e-Invoice\ProcesseInvoice.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\syswow64\KERNELBASE.dll
Report Id: dfaca8c6-b7d6-11e7-b19f-005056b765a3
```

Don't know what the problem is and in which direction I have to look.

Comment: this might help.....https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2013/07/30/learn-how-to-configure-powershell-memory/

Answer (score 0):

Pretty stupid, seemed that the processinvoicing*32.exe was still running under processes on the server. The logging in Powershell and eventviewer where not that clear.